# Creating a single menu across multiple web pages - without PHP

Tags: html, django, web

I'm working to build a website with django. I want to implement a single menu across multple [infinite] web pages. What is the best way to do this?

I'd really like to somehow make an html document and then reference it from my other pages. That way I can just make changes to a single document and it will effect all the pages.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not good at django but wouldn't simple `{%include 'menu.html'%}` work?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is extend a template.

Make a file called something like `base.html`. In this file, put your menu, or anything else you want across all of your pages.

Then, include something that looks like this.

```
{% block content %} {% endblock %}
```

In the rest of your templates (for actually serving the content), you have to include the line  `{% extends "base.html" %}` as the very fist line.

Then surround your content with:

```
{% block content %}
    Your content Here
{% endblock %}
```

For more information see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#extends and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance

Answer (score 0):

For a simple solution use an `<iframe>` with a single `menu.html` file as source.

`<iframe src="menu.html"></iframe>`

Frames might not be the most efficient solution but it sure is the simplest.

This way you can get the same page in every page.

**Tip:** format it border less for a stealth integration!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is PHP. Take a look here:

page1.php:

```
<body>
<?php include('menu.html'); ?>
page 1 content
page 1 content
</body>
```

page2.php:

```
<body>
<?php include('menu.html'); ?>
page 2 content
page 2 content
</body>
```

pageinfinite.php:

```
<body>
<?php include('menu.html'); ?>
pageinfinite content
pageinfinite content
</body>
```

and on: menu.html

```
<a href="page1.php">Page 1</a>
<a href="page1.php">Page 2</a>
<a href="page1infinite.php">Page infinite</a>
```

if you will add another item in menu.html, it will appear on every page!

Nice, huh?